# jquery slide and timing

Tags: jquery, html, timing, slide

hey there, i have a div that expands when the page is loaded, now i need it to collapse after 30 seconds, does anybody have an idea about how to do it in query?

```
$(function(){
    $("#banner").slideDown(); 
    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    $("#banner").slideDown(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#banner").slideUp();
        }, 30000);
    });
});
```

Comment: i forgot to say thank you! sorry i was on a hurry, now that i see the function it was kind of obvious isn´t it?? xD it works really nice.
thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 1):

To do this you'll need to use setTimeout

```
$(function(){
        //something
        setTimeout("slidedown()",30000);
}

function slidedown(){
   $("#banner").slideDown()
}
```